# Replace Assembly.LoadFrom(String, Evidence) call with Assembly.LoadFrom(String) - .NET 4

Tags: security, c#-4.0, c#-2.0, code-access-security, assembly-loading

I have to move some old `.NET 2` code to the `.NET 4` project. It has the next line:

```
`return Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence);`
```

As it said in Microsoft's ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s032xzec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)):

> Note: This API is now obsolete. The non-obsolete alternative is LoadFrom(String).

I'm not familiar with the `Evidence` class. What is the **risk** of just removing the `Evidence` parameter from the call? What is the real case when the `Evidence` parameter is necessary?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evidence argument was used to provide data that the Code Access Security (CAS) policy mechanism could use when deciding which CAS permissions to grant to the assembly being loaded.  However, in .NET 4.0, the "naked" CLR no longer uses CAS policy ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2010/02/24/so-is-cas-dead-in-net-4-or-what.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/06/12/clr-v4-security-policy-roundup.aspx), so the used of evidence in API has been deprecated.  There are usually only two reasons why one might have provided evidence in a LoadFrom call in code targeting an earlier .NET version:

1. To allow the assembly to run with more permissions than it might have otherwise been granted, or
2. To restrict the permissions of the assembly, removing permissions that would otherwise have been granted under the default evidence for the assembly.

For #1, you probably have nothing to do in .NET 4.0 since all code will run with unrestricted CAS permissions (aka "full trust") by default.  For #2, the recommended approach is to use a [sandboxed appdomain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/08/08/449050.aspx).